# Are there any Gary-Kleck-like studies on defensive gun uses for countries other than the USA? Specifically, I am interested in Croatia

Tags: guns, croatia

Is anybody here aware of some Gary-Kleck-like studies on defensive gun uses in Croatia? How often do guns save lives here in Croatia? If I get stuck in a debate about gun control, I guess that pointing to a study about Croatia might be a more compelling argument than pointing to Gary Kleck.

Comment: Are you more interested in Croatia at peace, or during the 1990s Balkan conflict.  I found this M. Kuzman, B. Tomic, R. Stevanovic et al., "Fatalities in the War in Croatia, 1991 and 1992: Underlying
and External Causes of Death" Which looks at deaths during the war.  Clearly some Croat civilians used weaponry in self defence against Serb (etc) soldiers and militia

Comment: @JamesK At peace, of course. The more recent, the better.

Comment: By "Gary Kleck like" do you mean "inaccurate and exaggerated"?

Comment: Some relevant statistics with sources are listed at https://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/compare/Croatia/United-States/Crime See also https://total-croatia-news.com/news/croatian-gun-owners/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overview_of_gun_laws_by_nation#Croatia